# Facebook-like photo/video/link posting plugin in BuddyPress

Tags: buddypress

I am working on BuddyPress. I am new in BuddyPress. Is there any plugin, something like `Facebook-like photo/video/link posting plugin` at the time when we update status?

Comment: Closing, from the official reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is one.

Try http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/media-embeds-for-buddypress-activity

Answer (score 1):

Even You can try much better with premium plugin like [rtMedia](https://rtcamp.com/rtmedia/) in which you can have media support for your forum.

Though if your requirement is only activity link posting than Buddypress Activity Plus is a choice.